# Scala Solution for consecutive products

Tags: scala

I was solving a problem using scala and my solution is:

```
object ConsecutiveProduct extends App {

 def getConsecutiveProduct(group: Int, number: String): Int = {
   val result = number.sliding(group).map(product)

  result.max
 }

 def product(number: String): Int = number.map(_.asDigit).product

 val str = """73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
          |96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
          |85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
          |12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
          |66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
          |62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
          |30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
          |70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
          |65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
          |52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
          |53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
          |83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
          |82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
          |16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
          |17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
          |24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
          |07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
          |84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
          |05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
          |71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450""".filter(_.isDigit)
      println(getConsecutiveProduct(5, str))
 }
```

So according to problem one has to calculate highest adjacent digits product, for input of 5 adjacent digits that have highest product I got the result right as `40824`, but according to problem when I pass 13 here `println(getConsecutiveProduct(13, str))` i.e highest product of consecutive 13 digits I get the result as '2091059712', but its not the correct answer as I tried to input in the respective website, I tried debugging but can't find where I am doing wrong, somebody help please.

Comment: You might want to use the `stripMargin` method on your string, rather than a filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sought product exceeds a 32-bit integer, so there's overflow. Use `Long` instead. This includes the result of `asDigit` as well, i.e.:

```
number.map(_.asDigit.toLong).product
```